# typescrpt me devuelve: No se puede asignar a "templatePush" porque es una propiedad de solo lectura

Tags: typescript

Estoy intentando probarla función createPush con jest, para ello quiero realizar un mock de templatePush, pero cuando importo templatePush e intento generar un mock, typescript me indica que no lo puedo hacer porque esta función tiene la propiedad de solo lectura:

```
    import * as git from '../tasks/TASK/git';
    import * as GitInterfaces from 'azure-devops-node-api/interfaces/GitInterfaces';
    
    git.templatePush = jest.fn(() => {
        return gitRepository
    })
```

git.templatePush me genera el error de readOnly. Pasa lo mismo con cualquier función o variable que importe desde el modulo git.

Así es como luce el módulo git:

```
    import * as common from 'azure-devops-task-utils';
    import * as tl from '../node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/task';
    import * as GitInterfaces from 'azure-devops-node-api/interfaces/GitInterfaces';
    
    export async function createPush(): Promise<GitInterfaces.GitPush> {
      try {
        const buildRepositoryName: string = tl.getVariable('BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME')!;
        const webApi = await common.getWebApi();
        const gitApi = await webApi.getGitApi();
        const project = common.getProject();
        const repository = await gitApi.getRepository(buildRepositoryName);
    
        const temPush = templatePush(repository);
        const repoId: string = repository.id!;
    
        return await gitApi.createPush(temPush, repoId, project)
    
      } catch (error:any) {
        console.log(error.message);
        throw new Error(error.message); 
      }
    }
    
    export function templatePush(repository: GitInterfaces.GitRepository): GitInterfaces.GitPush {
      const buildRequestedFor: string = tl.getVariable('BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR')!;
      const buildRequestedForEmail: string = tl.getVariable('BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL')!;
      
      return <GitInterfaces.GitPush>{
        commits: [
            author: {
              date: new Date(),
              email: `${buildRequestedForEmail}`,
              name: `${buildRequestedFor}`
            }]
      }
}
```

¿Por qué typescript me indica que la propiedad es de solo lectura cuando yo no lo he indicado en ningún momento? ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se siga generando ese error?

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

No se al cierto por qué te indica que la propriedad es de solo lectura pero mi sugerencia es que uses `spyOn` y `mockImplementation`. Algo como:

```js
import * as git from '../tasks/TASK/git';
import * as GitInterfaces from 'azure-devops-node-api/interfaces/GitInterfaces';

const templatePushSpy = jest.spyOn(git, 'templatePush').mockImplementation(jest.fn(() => gitRepository));
```